# Find duplicate directory trees on a Mac

Tags: macos, duplicate, directory-listing

Sounds dumb, but actually, I'm not looking for single duplicate files (which is easily achieved via either specific programs or via command line tools like diff), but for complete directory trees (including the files, of course) I expect to have on my computer. Taking a file search and checking the individual location of each file is not easy to be handled - think of the copy of a folder with music or images. Having an individual file with several copies is not a problem nowadays (I don't really care about 5MB), but a complete artist with several albums in several instances might still be annoying. And after nearly 20 years of copying files back and forth, I'm pretty sure I have forgotten some "backups" in obscure locations.

**tl;dr:**
I want to have a list of entire directories which appear repeatedly on my machine (different drives possibly) - this would mean that the directories have the same content (files or other directories).
Being identical, I would consider content (to start with: size) and name being identical, owner and date might differ.